# Day difference between two dates in XSLT version 2.

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Is there a easy way I can get how many days is the difference between two dates in XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [subtract](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-subtract-dates) one `xs:date` from another one and then you get an `xs:dayTimeDuration` of which you can extract components e.g. `xs:date('2015-06-11') - xs:date('2015-06-01')` gives an `xs:dayTimeDuration` `P10D` and you can then call http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-days-from-duration e.g. `days-from-duration(xs:date('2015-06-11') - xs:date('2015-06-01'))` which gives `10`.